# I am getting Missing Purpose String but i have added that in info.plist The Missing Purpose String is "NSNearbyInteractionAllowOnceUsageDescription"

Tags: swift, info.plist, multipeer-connectivity

The Error I am getting on email from Apple App Store while I am publishing my app to Apple App Store Testflight from my mac , although I am unable to see my build on testflight forum.And the email from Apple App Store is as under.

> Dear Developer,
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "IDTAG Nearby Interaction" 1.0 (1.0). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSNearbyInteractionAllowOnceUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

I have already the below strings into my `Info.plist`

```
<key>Privacy - Nearby Interaction Allow Once Usage Description</key>
    <string>Nearby Interaction app uses our u1 chip for better experience to show other peers location.</string>
    <key>Privacy - Nearby Interaction Usage Description</key>
    <string>Nearby Interaction app uses our u1 chip for better experience to show other peers location.</string>
```

According to Apple Documentation

( Nearby Interaction Allow Once Usage Description ) will be deprecated in iOS 15. That's why I have already added ( Privacy - Nearby Interaction Usage Description ) in my project but still I am having the above mentioned issue in my project by Apple store.